# Why am I getting docked reputation for someone else's answer?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

Maybe I'm confused, but when I hit up my reputation tab I see a -1 reputation for the following answer being downvoted: [waiting for all pids to exit in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198844/waiting-for-all-pids-to-exit-in-php/16351114#16351114)

I didn't write that answer, so I don't understand why I'm receiving negative reputation.  I do remember reading a question very much like it, so it's likely I read the answer at some point, but I don't have anything to do with it.

Anyone understand why this might happen?

Comment: Did you downvote it?

Comment: I'll wager that you're getting downvotes here because of lack of research. Your answer is contained in the Help Center: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Well, putting it in the help center is good and all, but if a Google search and Stack Exchange site search doesn't come up with the answer, I'd say that's not entirely my fault.

Comment: What did you search for? [1](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+does+reputation+work+on+stack+overflow) [2](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=why+did+i+lose+reputation+on+stack+overflow)

Comment: Pretty much the question in the title.  On Google I added Stack Exchange to the query.

Comment: I understand why.  I was mischaracterizing the problem.  But I didn't know that at the time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Downvoting answers is not free. You downvoted that answer and that costs -1 rep.

When you downvote an answer, the reputation tab entry says *downvoted*:

[image: downvoted, you voted]

If someone else downvotes one of your posts, the cost is -2 rep and this is shown as *downvote* instead:

[image: downvote, you received a vote]

Note the difference in both amount and the entry text.

Downvoting questions is free.